# Should I use gettext for a PHP application?

Tags: php, translation

I'm trying to add i18n support for my open-source PHP project.  I've been trying to use `gettext`, but I am running into some issues which I could see being a problem down the road.

For example, the way that caching requires one to restart the web server is frustrating during development.  The [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625659/how-to-clear-phps-gettext-cache-without-restart-apache-nor-change-domain?lq=1) I've seen are hacky, and several people have suggested that `gettext` doesn't make sense for the web and should be deprecated.  I would agree, and add that the `.po` format itself seems outdated, especially in the modern world of JSON and XML.

I also don't like that the main tool (poEdit) for generating and editing the `.po` translation files is freemium, rather than completely free.

That being said, is there a real alternative?  I saw php-gettext, but I can't tell if it is still actively maintained.  Ideally, I'd like something that is:

- Widely used (maybe it's just hiding from me?)
- Actively maintained
- Works out of the box (doesn't require special web server configuration)
- Available on Packagist

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731105/is-gettext-the-best-way-to-localise-a-website-in-php-only-mild-localisation-ne) suggests that `gettext` is the right way to go, but at this point the question is over 2 years old.  As we know, a lot can change in software over two years.

Comment: Nope, it should be asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/  If you are at a PC, ask s.o, if you are at a whiteboard, ask programmers. S.O expects you post some code and explain how it doesn't work. Programmers handles questions like this

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if either of those places are appropriate when looking for an explicit recommendation.